# three.js: capture video frame for later use

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three.js r73. I have a fragment shader that display video frames with a line like this:

```
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( iChannel0,  uv);
```

I would like another uniform (say iChannel1) to contain the video frame that was displayed at some earlier point. (Then I'll do some masking between iChannel0 and iChannel1 to do motion capture/edge detection etc).

I've tried various approaches to this, but no luck.

I figure that I need to clone the video texture somehow in javascript and then assign it to iChannel1, but I don't know how to capture a frame.

I guess I could capture the canvas content but there might be other noise on the canvas that I don't want. I truly want the video frame not the canvas. Also going via canvas capture seems very roundabout. I feel like I'm just missing some API call to capture the current video frame in a way that I can make a texture that iChannel1 will use.

I looked at UniformsUtils but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this shortly after posting my question. D'oh.

Here is the way, for future reference:

```
if (timeToCaptureFrame) {
    that.uniforms.iChannel1.value.image = that.uniforms.iChannel0.value.image;
    that.uniforms.iChannel1.value.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Note that iChannel1 needs to be initialized correctly for this to work. Something like this works:

```
var pathToSubtractionTexture = 'aStillImage.jpg';
(new THREE.TextureLoader()).load(pathToSubtractionTexture, function ( texture ) {
    that.uniforms.iChannel1.value = texture;
});
```